# how use result of findall in conditon of dataprovider?

Tags: yii

i want to use result of findall which is array in condition of cactivedataprovider ?

```
 $criteria->condition = 'department_id=:email';
    $criteria->params = array(':email'=>$id);
    $subject_ids=subject::model()->findAll($criteria);

public function myDataProvider($subject_ids)
{

    foreach($subject_ids as $value){
        print_r($value);
        foreach($value as $val){
            echo $val;
        }
    }
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Lecture', array(
        'criteria'=>array(

            'condition'=>'subject_id='+$val,
        )
    ));

    return $dataProvider;

}
```

how i should use the array has multy rows

Answer (score 1):

You function should looks like

```
public function myDataProvider($subject_ids)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('subject_id=', $subject_ids);
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Lecture', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria
    ));

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But $subject_ids is not array of int in your example, so you can do that:

```
$ids = CHtml::listData(subject::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'id');
```

and you will get ids.